# Dynamic memory allocation using malloc()

Tags: c, memory-management, operating-system

How is memory allocated using malloc() ? Who allocates the memory OS or the compiler? Once the memory is freed using free() can it be used by other processes ?

Comment: ask one question at a time, and use the search function as these have all been asked and answered before on here

Comment: I don't see any problem with the question other than that it probably has been asked before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an OS there are 4 memory regions Heap,Stack,Text and Data. When you use malloc the OS provides the memory from the heap region. Compiler isn t responsible for allocating this memory. When you use free the memory block is returned back to the heap.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the heap memory is directly supplied by a runtime sub-allocator underneath whatever the OS provides.  The sub-allocator is process-specific and does not require a kernel call.  If the heap needs more, it has to resort to a syscall to get another chunk from the OS.

It's implementation-specific whether the sub-allocator ever releases chunks back to the OS.